# Importing/parsing XML from URL into Magento

Tags: magento, import, xml-parsing

I have a URL, which contains XML of products.

What I'm looking to do, is, if possible, parse the contents and then import the details as products into Magento.

Is this possible and If so, what would be the steps I need to do to carry this out?

Thanks

EDIT:

import_products.php

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');

class import_products extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

 public static function url_contents($url)
 {
   $crl = curl_init();
   $timeout = 5;
   curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
   $ret = curl_exec($crl);
   curl_close($crl);
   return $ret;
}
```

}

import.php

```
require_once('import_products.php');

$app = Mage::app('default'); 
$product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');

$objDOM = new DOMDocument();
$objDOM->load("http://www.example.com/products.xml");

$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("car");
// for each note tag, parse the document and get values for
// tasks and details tag.

foreach( $note as $value )
{
  $car_ids = $value->getElementsByTagName("Car_ID");
  $car_id  = $car_ids->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $makes = $value->getElementsByTagName("Make");
  $make  = $makes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $models = $value->getElementsByTagName("Model");
  $model = $models->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $descriptions = $value->getElementsByTagName("Description");
  $description = $descriptions->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $short_descriptions = $value->getElementsByTagName("Specification");
  $short_description = $short_descriptions->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $prices = $value->getElementsByTagName("Price");
  $price  = $prices->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $simple = 'simple';
  $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
  $product->setSku($task);
  $product->setName($detail);
  $product->setTypeId($simple);
  $product->setPrice($price);
  $product->setValue($price);
  $product->setDescription($description);
  $product->setShortDescription($short_description);
  $product->setWeight(100);
  $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
  $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
  $product->setTaxClassId(2); 
  $product->setStockData(array(
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => 99999
  ));

  try {
     $product->save();
 echo "Saved";
  }
  catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo "<pre>".$ex."</pre>";
  }

  //echo "$car_id :: $make :: $model ::  $description :: $short_description :: $price <br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I've looked at using Advanced Profiles: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/2448/ but it doesn't seem to connect via curl and save the file in /var/import - Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could get the parameter in Magento and use simple xml to turn the string into xml

```
$xmlstr = self::XML_DECLARATION . urldecode($this->getRequest()->getParam('paramName');
  try {
      $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
  }
  catch(Exception $ex) {
      echo "Unable to process xml file because of the following error<br /><br /> $ex";
      exit;
  }
```

if it is a file you are trying to get you can setup a php file with the following code in it to get the contents of the url

```
function get_url_contents($url){
$crl = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$ret = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
return $ret;
```

}

You can use that function and then where in the above we had

```
$xmlstr = self::XML_DECLARATION . urldecode($this->getRequest()->getParam('paramName');
```

You should be able to do this

```
$xmlstr = self::XML_DECLARATION . get_url_contents('http://urlhere.com/xml');
```

Then you could use simple xml and assign the nodes to a products array, where you could have a collection of products and then loop through those and programmatically create the products in Magento with something like this, obviously change the values that might be hard coded for whatever you might need.

```
    $product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');

    // Build the product
    $product->setSku($productData['sku']);
    $product->setAttributeSetId(26);
    $product->setTypeId('simple');
    $product->setName($productData['description']);
    $product->setCategoryIds(array(162)); 
    $product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); 
    $product->setDescription($productData['description']);
    $product->setShortDescription($productData['description']);
    $product->setPrice($productData['price']); # Set some price
    $product->setWeight(4.0000);

    $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
    $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $product->setData('is_salable', '1');
    $product->setTaxClassId(2); # My default tax class
    $product->setStockData(array(
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => 99999
    ));

    try {
        $product->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        //Handle the error
    }
```

Comment: Well where is your URL going, is it a custom module you built? If it is you can put this in your controller.

Comment: The url is pointing to an external XML file - http://www.example.com/products.xml it would be nice if this import, was available as a URI: http://www.mymagentosite.com/import_products.php

Comment: Oh I thought you meant the url had xml in a param

Comment: I updated my answer, I haven't tried it out but I think it should be right. You would just have to create a file on the root directory or somewhere accessible from the web and do the curl method.

Comment: Ok, followed that. I had to remove the self: part off as it threw an error. Also, i'm not getting: Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found - do I need to create a class that extends the Mage class?

Comment: Right, I have created a class, with the get_url_contents function. The class extends  Mage_Core_Model_Abstract. I have then created a php file that includes this class file and then parses the xml and then tries to insert the data. When returning the exeception, I see there is an SQL problem: Errorexception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'value' cannot be null' etc - what 'value' field is this? i.e. what table? The error doesn't say which table

Comment: I think I would need to see what you are doing, maybe updated your question with your code

Comment: are you not setting the website? I think you have to set a website maybe?

Comment: What do you mean, setting the website?